# Set defaultValue to todays date in a Sequelize migration

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using Node Express with Sequelize and I want to set the defaultValue for the column "date" in the database to todays date. I tried with the following migration, but it didn't work, as it set the default date to be the same date as when I ran the migration. I want it to be set to the same date as when the row is created.

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Todos',
      'date',
      {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: new Date()
      }
    )
  },
```

I can't understand how that would work.

Answer (score 35):

You need to use as a default value the MySQL function `NOW()`.

So your column declaration should look like :

```
{ 
   type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
   allowNull: false,
   defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
}
```

Keep in mind that this will not populate the fields in your migration. They will be empty, since they were not created with sequelize.

Comment: Didn't work for me (2022-03-09), had to use `Sequelize.fn('now')`

Comment: Doesn't work for me on v6.33.0 (2023-10-25), still have to use `Sequelize.fn('now')`

Answer (score 30):

`Sequelize.NOW` will work in future but some versions(I tried 4.43.0) seem not support it.
I succeeded in setting `now()` with using `Sequelize.fn('now')` .

```js
{
  type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
  allowNull: false,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4679

Comment: I need to use `Sequelize.fn('now')` on v5 also.

Comment: I had to use `Sequelize.fn('NOW')` ("now" in uppercase)

Answer (score 20):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/645#issuecomment-18461231

```
  createdAt: {
                field: 'created_at',
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server users must use `literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')`

```js
createdAt: {
   field: 'created_at',
   type: DataTypes.DATE,
   allowNull: false,
   defaultValue: literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
}
```

Comment: ERROR: literal is not defined: this does not work for me.

Comment: So sorry I just address this. For whoever has the same issue, `literal` must be imported from sequelize, it is a helper function.

Answer (score 4):

Use "literal", see below.

```
updated_at: {
  allowNull: false,
  type: Sequelize.DATE, 
  defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TIME: 2022-05-18

[According to latest Sequelize Doc (version v6)](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#default-values)

```
sequelize.define('Foo', {
  bar: {
     type: DataTypes.DATETIME,
     defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
     // This way, the current date/time will be used to populate this column 
     (at the moment of insertion)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

```
createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('getdate')
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me.

```
createdAt: {
   field: 'created_at',
   type: DataTypes.DATE,
   allowNull: false,
   defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW')
}
```

Comment: could you put the json into a code block so that it is easier to read and explain a little about why this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me.

```
sale_date: {
  allowNull: false,
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.